# Convert txt file to xls, change a specific character, split the text in different columns

Tags: excel, powershell, character, batch-processing

UPDATE : my final working code (without "." to "," change)

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\test\*.txt 
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $a=(Get-item $file).BaseName
    Import-csv -Path $file  -Delimiter " " -Header "q", "Intensite", "Delta" |
    Export-xlsx -Path C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\test\$a.xlsx
}
```

---

I realized a scientific experiment that gave me **a lot** of results in several .txt files, and I would like for each .txt file to create a .xls Excel file with the proper layout.

I found a working PowerShell code to convert .txt to .xls. Here it is:

```
    $files = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\test\*.txt
    Write "Loading Files..."

    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible = $false
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
        $NewFilepath = $file.FullName -replace ".{4}$"
        $NewFilepath =  $NewFilepath + ".xls"
        $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath, 56)
    }

    Stop-Process -ProcessName EXCEL
    $Excel.Quit()"
```

However, I do not know how to:

- replace all points "." by commas ",",
- do the layout.

Currently, the results (only numbers) on Excel are arranged in line on 1 column, but I have 3 numbers per cell **separated by a space**. How to separate the 3 numbers per cell in 3 columns?

Comment: I would suggest changing it to a CSV. That is way easier in Powershell. Also if you want help splitting the columns, we will need to see some sample data.

Comment: Take a look at the [PSExcel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) module, it'll make this task much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your input files are formatted as '3 columns separated by a space' like this:

```
123 456 789
789 123 456
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

You can use the [PSExcel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) module, which has a `Export-XLSX` command.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\folder\txt-xl\*.txt |
    foreach {Import-Csv $_ -Delimiter " " -Header "Col1","Col2","Col3"} |
    Export-XLSX -Path C:\folder\txt-xl\export.xlsx
```

You can format the Excel file, add graphs and much more using that module, there's more info on this on the github page I linked to.

Comment: I am going to check this, thanks guys !
(not sure I will suceed on my own though :D)